# Will calcite take statistics from data directly?

Tags: apache-calcite

Can I give my entire dataset to calcite, so that it will take statistics from data itself?
If so, how can I import my dataset into calcite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calcite is not designed to store all of your data. You can use it to access data from a variety of sources but you need to provide your own stasitics.

Comment: Meaning is, even if I want to give table details like datatype/size of column, unique elements count, etc., I have to give them with my own struct. We cant give any of our dataset to calcite, so that calcite can process our data to process these statistics. Is that so?

Comment: Correct. That's currently the case.

Comment: So how to register our own struct to calcite via RelMetadataProvider?

Comment: @Anbu That's a separate question and I'd suggest you post a new question asking this.